# Cordova iOS Notification about current location

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, geolocation

So before any one shout duplicate, i have been reading stuff for hours on this i have made sure all code is in `document.addEventListener("deviceready"` and still getting this problem im using the latest version of cordova and the geolocation plugin `cordova install cordova-plugin-geolocation`

I have setup my config.xml to include

```xml
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>Allows events near you to be located.</string>
</edit-config>
```

i have double checked the `{app_name}-Info.plist` and it does contain the value for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` so the config.xml is valid and is working.

However i'm still seeing `'{app_name}.app/www/index.html' Would Like To Use Your Current Location` notice to users

The code I'm using is

```
var options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy:true};
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e){
        var currLocBtn = $('<div id="currentLocBtn">Use Current Location</div>');
        currLocBtn.click(function(){
            $("#lat").val(e.coords.latitude);
            $("#lng").val(e.coords.longitude);
            $("#locInp").val("").attr("placeholder", "Current Location");
            $("#cordsText").val("Current Location");
            $("#cordsDisplay").text("Current Location");
        });
        $("#searchoverlay").prepend(currLocBtn);
    }, function(){}, options);
}, false);
```

If i run 
`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((e) => console.log(e), (e) => console.log(e));` from the web inspector console on my app it does the same its like the cordova wrapper is not working.

Comment: Pretty sure this is normal? Are you having any functional issues?

Comment: it should go though Codova use the app SDK location system so it then uses the .plist config and says what's configured in the plist, not use the browser native `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` which is what its doing, it's supposed to be overwriting the browser native with it's own.

Comment: I just made brand new cordova application with geolocation and a .js file containing a single 'deviceready' function that calls `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` and it works as you say it should. A simple javascript runtime error can cause the issue you are seeing

Comment: Yeah, but im using the Web Inspector and there are no JS errors occurring.

Comment: Have you tried running the `getCurrentPosition` function without your code? Make the function empty. Your last comment suggests your code might be the cause of the issue. Your second `function() {}` should have an `event` parameter as well.

Comment: yeah it should but Javascript support overloading it will just go into arguments[0] if i don't supply, i have also tried a very basic HTML page with just a button on it and a "deviceready" event that binds a click and it was doing exactly the same its like the plugin is not being built into my project by xcode trying a clean and complete rebuild now hopefully it will fix the xcode project

Comment: When is run this in a single .js file I have no issues: `document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() { navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) { console.info(pos) }); }, false);`

Comment: make sure you are also running `cordova prepare` each time you modify your javascript\

Comment: I'm doing that, clean did not work so im removing the platform and re-adding it now see if that sorts out the project

Comment: yeah that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was apprently caused by the build system messing up the xcode project. with prepare and build command the plugins we're not being linked into the xcode project to fix this i had to use

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

This forced it to remove and rebuild the xcode project file and fixed the problem.